# HP SAS HDD in an EMC VNX storage?

Tags: storage, hp, sas, emc

Would it be possible to use HP SAS 6G DP 300GB 10K SFF drives in an EMC VNX 5100 storage unit, which currently holds EMC 10K SFF drives (these are really Seagate Savvio 10K.5 SFF drives).

Generally, what are disk make/model limitations upon such storage systems?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it :)

Just use the disks that you *should* be using in the EMC. EMC may have specific firmware editions for their drives, just like HP and Dell may apply specific firmware to their drives. You're under support with your expensive EMC, right?

Either way, the HP drives are usually just [Seagate Savvio](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/2-5/savvio-10k/) and Westen Digital. I haven't seen anything else recently.

Comment: Thanks. I have some free disk bays left in the EMC, and some extra HP drives, so I thought to put the two together to extend the EMC.

Answer (score 3):

If you put anything other than the drives provided by EMC into a VNX, it will absolutely void the warranty. It will also not work. Each storage vendor puts standard drives into a proprietary cage (or shell, if you want) which is not sold separately, and is probably designed to make what you're trying to do impossible.